# Numpy create array from list of integers specifying the array elements

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, vectorization

Say we have the list `a = [3,4,2,1]`, from `a` we want to obtain the following array: `b = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,3]`.

I have managed to do it like this:

```
import numpy as np 
a = [3,4,2,1]
b = np.concatenate([[i] * n for i, n in enumerate(a])
print(b)
```

Output:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3])
```

Which works fine, but I can't help but wonder if there is a better way?

**EDIT**
@mathfux's solution is much more elegant than mine by simply using `np.repeat`. I benchmarked the two using `perfplot`, here the results:
[image]
Benchmark code:

```
import numpy as np
import perfplot

out = perfplot.bench(
    setup=lambda n: np.arange(n),
    kernels=[
        lambda x: np.concatenate([[i] * n for i, n in enumerate(x)]),
        lambda x: np.repeat(range(len(x)), x)
    ],
    n_range=np.arange(128, 128 * 16, 128),
    labels=[
        "concat",
        "repeat"
    ],
    xlabel='np.arange(x)'
)
out.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html): `np.repeat([0,1,2,3], [3,4,2,1])`